# jQuery DatePicker в Сафари не отключает даты

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, datepicker, jquery-form

У меня есть двумерный массив дат, которые пользователь не может выбирать. DatePicker не отключает эти даты именно в Сафари и пользователь без проблем может выбрать любую из этих дат, во всех браузерах работает как надо, код такой:

```html
    var holidays = [
    [1,12],
    [3,12],
    [4,12],
    [7,12]
];      
        $( ".ddate" ).datepicker({
        
        beforeShowDay: function(date){
            for (var i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++) {
                if (holidays[i][0] == date.getDate() && holidays[i][1] - 1 == date.getMonth()) {
                    return [false];
                }
            }
            return [true];
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, вдруг кому пригодится, она оказывается была в коде ниже, при формировании minDate.

Вместо:

```
$( ".ddate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(2020, 11, 20) );
```

Сделал:

```
$( ".ddate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(2020, 11-1, 20) );
```

И все заработало.